# What is a non-alcoholic substitute for rum in a glaze?

Tags: baking, substitutions, alcohol, glaze, rum

I want to make an orange cake and its recipe calls for rum in the glaze. Rum, anything alcoholic, rum extract, etc. are not an option for me. Is there a way to substitute with vanilla extract? If so, in what proportion?

According to the recipe, for glaze we need:

- ½ cup strained fresh orange juice
- 1 Tbsp. unsalted butter, melted
- 2 Tbsp. dark rum
- 1 cup confectioners' sugar, divided

I have looked at the answers to [What is substitute for rum in baking?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/7703/what-is-substitute-for-rum-in-baking), but they focus mostly on dough/batter and aren't very specific about method of proportion.

Comment: Please provide the full method; 1/2 c. of orange juice would give you more of a syrup than a glaze with only 1 c. sugar, even without the rum.

Comment: According to the recipe, initially I add only 1/2 cup sugar to the mixture and let the cake soak only 1/2 part of the solution. Remaining 1/2 sugar is added to rest of the solution and used to top the cake before serving. I assume the first one is syrup to be soaked and the other one glaze.

Answer (score 5):

The rum is just for flavor so you can skip it entirely if you like, just make up the liquid with more orange juice. If you want to use vanilla, just try 1/8 - 1/4 tsp. If you'd like the flavor of rum without the alcohol, non-alcoholic "rum" does exist (spiced rum here, which would be nice with orange). [Non-alcoholic "Liquors"](http://shop.arkaybeverages.com/21-alcohol-free-rum?p=2) Just in case you'd like to know, these products are Halal certified. [Halal Certificate](http://shop.arkaybeverages.com/content/28-halal-certificates)

Answer (score 2):

I have tried many recipes that contained rum and I substituted it with a concentrated mixture of orange and lemon juice and the result was quite good. The mixture is made by boiling the juices and allowing it to reduce (shed off some moisture via evaporation).

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice Nibal Nibal! I have suggested an edit to help clarify your answer a little. A reduced mixture of orange and lemon juice sounds tasty to me. It seems you could use that for all sorts of different applications.

Answer (score 1):

There are aroma substances developed to replace rum and other common baking flavors (including vanilla extract, which in its normal form contains alcohol).

An example are [Dr Oetker's](http://www.amazon.de/Dr-Oetker-Rum-Aroma/dp/B003TOHAVG) aromas. I don't know about their availability in different parts of the world, but they are fairly common in many European countries.